# How to make an automated browser to specific web site in server mode ? what about WATIR?

Tags: linux, watir, watir-webdriver

I need to make a server which is listening for clients requests and use a connection to a website to make searches and return results to its clients.

The website is specific and need full web browser with javascript support to works. Also, it needs authentication, and i can make only one request at a time. So i need to use a queue to send requests if they come simultanously.

Preferred platform is Linux.
I found WATIR project, is there other ways and what is the best one ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what is your preferred language? (programming, not spoken)

Answer (score 1):

Watir works on Linux and I think it could do the job. You can even drive [headless Firefox](http://watirwebdriver.com/headless/) and PhantomJS if the server is headless.